# Teamcity how to recreate foulder structure

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity

I need a hint of how to recreate the current folder structure on Teamcity (and if it's possible or not).

```
Project folder
- machine_app_1 - //repo1
- machine_app_2 - //repo2
- common_code   - //repo3
- ...various common files...
```

So, I have a folder with 3 repositories inside it and some sparse files inside it. I need to recreate this structure since the machine_app code needs the common code to build (and the builder is between the "various common files", so I need them too).

Should I use artifacts? And where should I place them? Or should I edit the checkout folder? Should I put the files directly.. where? I'm a bit confused of all the way of working of Teamcity and I cannot make it work.

I've also tried creating a shell script that reorders the files but it's a mess to do it that way, also because the foulder structure is not that easy and I keep having a lot of locking problems.

Thanks :)

Comment: Which folder structure are you talking about? Are you referring to your source code structure? More details required for sure.

Comment: I've explained it a little better in detail :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to place source code files in the correct folder structure rather than compiled binaries the correct answer is to use checkout rules for the VCS checkout roots rather than artifacts.

To achieve this you would attach a VCS root for each of your three repositories to the build configuration and then for each one define the checkout rules to place the files where they need to be. For instance, to move the files from repository 1 to a folder called machine_app_1 you would define the rule like this:

[image: VCS checkout rule example]

This is a simple example and if necessary you can create rules that are much more complicated. For full details, the best resource is the [TeamCity documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/VCS+Checkout+Rules)

Answer (score 1):

I've used grunt for this before. There is a grunt runner you can use
[here](https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity.Node). It would be easier if we knew exactly the big picture of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If they are separate repositories, I think you can create multiple [VCS roots](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Roots) (one for each repo) and use [VCS checkout rules](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/VCS+Checkout+Rules) to put the stuff in your desired folders.